# Migrating from webpack/CRA to snowpack: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module X does not provide an export named Y

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-konva, konva, snowpack

Please help me understand what is causing the error message below.

I'm trying to migrate a project to Snowpack, having used create-react-app previously. In this project I am using a library called react-konva for some canvas stuff. This library works fine when used in create-react-app, but when I try to use it with snowpack I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../web_modules/react-konva.js' does not provide an export named 'Rect'
```

I error above was raised by this snippet:

```js
import { Layer, Rect, Stage } from 'react-konva';

const ReactKonvaTest = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Stage width={800} height={500}>
        <Layer>
          <Rect width={200} height={100} strokeWidth={10} stroke="#222" />
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    </>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactKonvaTest />
      <p>
        Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The same snippet does not cause any problems when used in a project initialized with create-react-app.

I don't understand whats causing it. Im not sure what `../web_modules/` directory in the error message is referring to. I have not heard of it before, and my searches haven't yielded any relevant matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed with `react-konva@17.0.1-1`